# Android app crashes on onLoadFinished()

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I'm using an SQLite database to store objects called Reservations, that are displayed in a ListView. I used to use a cursor with the deprecated function startManagingCursor(), but it crashed my app when the activity in which the ListView is displayed.

So I tried to use CursorLoaders and ContentProviders instead, with which I did this:

```
    package com.example.my.app;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FlightBook extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    private ListView ReservationList = null;
    private Cursor c = null;
    private ReservationsBDD rdb = new ReservationsBDD(this);
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    private static final int LOADER_ID = 0;
    private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {MaBaseSQLite.getColReference(), MaBaseSQLite.getColLastname()};//{ "_id", "text_column" };
    private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> mCallbacks;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flight_book);

        ReservationList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.flightList);

        //Initialiser la base de données
        rdb.open();

        String[] from = { MaBaseSQLite.getColLastname() }; //{ "text_column" };
        int[] to = { R.id.reference_entry, R.id.lastname_entry }; //{ R.id.text_view };

        /* Display the bdd */
        //mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getBaseContext(), R.layout.flight_book_list, c, from, to);

        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.flight_book_list, null, from, to, 0);
        mCallbacks = this;

        ReservationList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, mCallbacks);

        //Gérer le clic simple sur un élément de la listView
        ReservationList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            long selectedItemID = 0;
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                Reservation res = rdb.getReservationWithID(id);

                   //Afficher l'activité adéquate
                   Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ReservationInfo.class);
                   myIntent.putExtra("ReservationReference", res.getReference());
                   myIntent.putExtra("LastName", res.getLastname());
                   startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });

        //Gérer le clic long sur un élément de la listView
        ReservationList.setOnItemLongClickListener (new OnItemLongClickListener() 
        {
            long selectedItemID = 0;

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                //selectedItemID = ((View) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getId();
                return onLongListItemClick(view, position, id);
            }
            protected boolean onLongListItemClick(final View v, final int pos, long id) 
            {
               final String str=ReservationList.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
               Log.i("ListView", "onLongListItemClick string=" + str);
               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FlightBook.this);
               builder.setMessage("Delete this entry from Flight Book?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
               {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                   {
                       Log.i("ID",""+pos);
                       rdb.removeReservationWithID((int)mAdapter.getItemId(pos));
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
               {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                   {
                       dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
               AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
               alert.show();
               return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        mAdapter.changeCursor(null);
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        rdb.close();
    }

    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_flight_book, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new CursorLoader(FlightBook.this, ReservationProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    }

    //@Override -> won't work, says "must override a superclass method"
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) 
    {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    //@Override -> won't work, says "must override a superclass method"
      public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) 
      {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
      }
}
```

For some reason I've been investigating, the app crashes as soon as I launch this activity.

Here's my ContentProvider:

```
package com.example.my.app;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;

public class ReservationProvider extends ContentProvider 
{
    private ReservationsBDD mDB;
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.my.app.ReservationProvider";
    public static final int RESERVATION = 100;
    public static final int RESERVATION_ID = 110;
    private static final String RESERVATIONS_BASE_PATH = "reservations";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/" + RESERVATIONS_BASE_PATH);
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE
            + "/mc-reservation";
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE
            + "/mt-reservation";

    private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    static 
    {
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, RESERVATIONS_BASE_PATH, RESERVATION);
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, RESERVATIONS_BASE_PATH + "/#", RESERVATION_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri arg0, String arg1, String[] arg2) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri arg0, ContentValues arg1) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() 
    {
        mDB = new ReservationsBDD(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) 
    {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setTables(mDB.getMaBaseSQLite().TABLE_RESERVATION);
        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (uriType) 
        {
            case RESERVATION_ID:
                queryBuilder.appendWhere(ReservationsBDD.COL_ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
                break;
            case RESERVATION:
                // no filter
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI");
        }
        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(mDB.getMaBaseSQLite().getReadableDatabase(), projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri arg0, ContentValues arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

What did I get wrong? :( 
Thanks in advance.

PS: ReservationsBDD is a DAO to get items from MaBaseSQLite which is an SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: Could you post the log please.

Comment: I didn't post it because there's nothing in it. Just this: {at com.example.my.app.FlightBook.onLoadFinished(FlightBook.java:176)}
 and the same with line 1 instead of 176.

:1 points to the package name
:176 to mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
at com.example.my.app.FlightBook.onLoadFinished(FlightBook.java:1)